# how to save element created with javascript to local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is it possible to save element to local storage then call it from it
this an example for what I'm trying to do

```
let div = document.createElement("div");

localStorage.setItem("div",div)

document.body.appendChild(localStorage.getItem("div"))
```

Comment: `localStorage` supports only string data

Comment: Why don't store the `id` or `class` of the div element and then retrieve the same and find the corresponding DOM element.

Comment: read this article it might help. It does not store the html elements themselves but recreates them whenever its loaded again  https://dev.to/michaelburrows/how-to-save-data-in-localstorage-using-javascript-994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as such.

Values in local storage must be *strings* and DOM elements are not strings.

You would need to serialise the data. Most applications would use JSON and store business data rather then anything that *directly* represents the rendered view but you could store HTML source code.